# Basic PIC programming

Tags: assembly, pic

I recently started studying PIC programming because I need to do a project on it, and I would like to ask you a few questions.

So I have a program:

```
org 0
loop movlw 03
     addlw 05
     movwf 30
     goto loop
     end
```

I learned so far that movlw will add value "03" to register W, addlw will add value "05" and movwf should move the W value to specified register. But I thought it needs to be specified whether it is binary or hex, and on my datasheet on "PIC16F877A" I can't find register "30" (for example TRISA is 85h).

I would also like to know the address program starts on, program counter value change and values of registers that changed for every line of that program.

I also need to know how many bits do the commands take.

Comment: `movwf 30` is "move register w to file 30." Look up on the data sheet how many files this PIC has, and look up on the assembler doc the default number base, to establish if this is file 30 or 48 (decimal). It's not binary. As far as I recall, it's not relevant what address the code starts on, or how many bits in an instruction (14 in some?) since this is beyond reach.

Comment: What exactly are "files" on PIC? I checked all over datasheet and nothing resembling it was found.

Comment: Example `bsf` is the mnemonic for "bit set file". A *file* is the PIC equivalent of a memory location. Some files have specialised usage for example file 0 which if I recall correctly is used for indirection (to other files). Files in some PICs are also bank-switched, that is, they have one purpose in one bank and a different purpose in another bank. If you don't know that you need a basic reference on PIC.

Comment: `org 0` is the address program starts on.